# SQL server order by case not working

Tags: sql-server

I have the following (edited) `select`, using a `view` and a `case` for the `ORDER BY` caluse:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VW_View 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN Initials = 'New' 
   THEN '1' 
   ELSE TeamID 
END 
ASC
```

This works fine on my local database, and returns this:

[image]

As expected

However, on the test database, it returns this:

[image]

Not as expected, eg the order by clause is  not working.

The views are exactly the same, so why would the clause not be consistent?

Comment: Is `TeamID` `Pending`? Why do you expect that at all?

Comment: Show the values present in `TeamID`

Comment: Values added - they are all 1 and are the same for both databases

Comment: the order by works just fine, you said order by teamid at thats what happend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you aren't defining a secondary sort, when TeamId = 1 the order is undefined.  Add a second sort condition or change to something like...

```
SELECT * 
FROM VW_View 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN Initials = 'New' 
   THEN '0' 
   ELSE TeamID 
END 
ASC
```